# adding a custom transition to presentViewController in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

i have a `viewController` which has a `TableView` and a cell with a `accessoryType` of `detailbutton`.
When pressing that `accessoryType` i present a semi transparent View with text.

I want this view to appear in a specific way so i created a custom view controller.

However trying to run that viewController in the `detailbutton` will not work.

parts of my code:

```
//Defined in the class
let customTransitionManager = TransitionManager()

//in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath
if (tableView == continent){
        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "continentSelector")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Continent"
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton;
        return cell


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    println(indexPath)
    let detailController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailButtonStoryBoard") as? detailedView
    detailController?.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
    detailController?.transitioningDelegate = customTransitionManager;
    presentViewController(detailController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Running this code gives me the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The following gets highlighted:

```
-> 0x100209cf0 <function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()+44>: brk    #0x1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two places where you could have an nil value.  The first is in the cell for row at index path, but that is unlikely.  The second and more likely one is where you try to unwrap the detailContoller when presenting it.  Have you confirmed that you are getting the controller back from the storyboard?

UPDATE:  The solution I put in the comments formatted horribly, here is a better format

Found a solution Use a segue instead of presenting the controller manually.

1. Call performSegue from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath
2. in the prepareForSegue method put this:

   ```
   let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
   toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.customTransitionManager`
   ```

Full credit goes to this tutorial: http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/#custom-transition-animations

UPDATE 2:  Downloaded your project and got it working.  Here are the changes I made:

1. I added a modal segue between the jeans controller and the detail controller.  I called this 'DetailSegue'
2. I updated the jeans.swift file accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method as follows:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
       println(indexPath)
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailSegue", sender: self)
   }
   ```
3. I then updated the TransitionManger animateTransition function as follows, basically making the to and from views optional and handling nil appropriately

   ```
   func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
       //get reference to our FROM View, To View, and container view that we should perform the transition in
       let container = transitionContext.containerView()

       let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
       let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)

       //setup from 2D transform that we'll use in the animation
       let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.width, 0)
       let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.width, 0)

       //start the view to the right of the screen 
       toView?.transform = offScreenRight

       //add both the views to our view controller
       if toView != nil {
           container.addSubview(toView!)
       }

       if fromView != nil {
           container.addSubview(fromView!)
       }

       // get the duration of the animation
       let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

       //perform the animation

       UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {
           fromView?.transform = offScreenLeft
           toView?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
           }, completion: { finished in transitionContext.completeTransition(true)})
   }
   ```

Here is a screencast of the final result: http://screencast.com/t/2mC07BLCC

I hope this helps you move forward with your project.

Comment: Yes because if I leave out detailController?.TransitionDelegate = customTransitionManager it does work. It's just using s show transition and not my custom. So I think for some reason my customViewController is empty. But that's onlikely too. Because when I press a other button it does work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your custom transition manager methods are getting called?

Comment: I setup a test and got the same error.  The issue seems to be that there is no 'from' view controller in transition context that is passed to the transition manager.  This is caused by the manual presentation you are doing.  The solution is to use a segue instead of presenting the view controller manually.  Here is what I did:

Comment: unfortunatly this doesnt work, i uploaded my code to github https://github.com/bbriann123/Clothes/blob/master/Clothes_Converter/Clothes%20Converter/jeans.swift If i leave jeans.swift (on the iphone) it does use the transition, just not with the acessorybutton

Comment: i Think it has to due to the fact Swift does not know which table view i am using.

Comment: Thanks so much! The only thing i need to know now is how to do a custom transition on the Exit of the segue, but i will figure that out!!!